# changes in live classes & existing clients in azure mobile services with dot net backend

Tags: azure-mobile-services

we have a live azure mobile service using dot net backend. The apps using it are out & people are using them. 
If we add a few more nullable fields to one of the classes in azure service, will the existing client apps keep working, without an update? 
Or do all users must require to update the app before continue using the services?

Answer (score 1):

Existing clients will keep working. On the client side, when it receives objects with properties which it doesn't understand the serializer will just ignore those. On the server side, when it receives the data from old clients, any properties which you have added to the class will have its default value (e.g., if you have a new integer property, it will have the value `0`, and for string properties the value `null`). As long as the logic in the service controller can handle those default values, then your application will be fine.

Comment: Thank you. We did some tests around it & found this is how its behaving.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity framework.Base on my test, it's OK.You don't have to change your client-side data model.

P.S. If you just change your entity class.It may clear your database.Be careful with that.

> If you want Entity Framework to alter your database
>   automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
>   For more information refer to the documentation:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: I am already using migrations. Thank you for confirmation I'll tun some tests today to see what it does with changes in data model.